# Buttons within dialog boxes and how to get the respective button value on form submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a razor view which has a form. Within the form there is a button called upload. The upload button posts to an action method which is working fine.

I want to add a modal box confirmation which would appear when they hit upload button, now within the modal box I want to have two buttons. One would say "Normal Parsing" and the other would say "Buffer Parsing".  Once they press either button within the dialog box, the form will submit to the action method and within the action method I want to see which dialog button they pressed, either "Normal Parsing" or "Buffer Parsing".

This is what I have so far for the dialog box,  I just need to see how will the controller get the value of the button pressed.  Thanks guys!!

```
function getParsingRoute(){
  var buttonPressed;
    .dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 600,
                title: 'Parsing Values Confirmation',
                buttons: {
                    "Normal Parsing": function () {
                        buttonPressed = "Normal";
                    },
                    "Buffer Parsing": function () {
                        buttonPressed = "Buffer
                    }
                }
            })
}

  @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

    <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="getParsingRoute()" style="width: 100px">Upload</button>
}
```

Comment: Maybe You should call action by javascript. These action will be additional send parameter which will be `buttonPressed`

Comment: Have the click handlers for the buttons fill in a hidden field in the form.

Comment: @jack it is MVC, The upload button is within a partial view. My preference is not to use any AJAX calls for this

Comment: @woocash is there an alternative besides ajax post from the dialog box

Comment: @tamtam MVC usually refers to the pattern, not a particular implementation such as asp.net-mvc; your question has been retagged properly :)

Comment: @Barmar I like your solution, so in the click handlers for the button if i set up hidden fields, the form will still post to the controller action method right, imean would i need to add any ajax calls in the dialog box?

Comment: See WooCaSh's answer, I think that should work.

Comment: @tamtam look on my second answer. Inspired by Bamar comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution inpired by ***@Barmar*** comment:

```
function getParsingRoute(e){
e.stopPropagation();
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Parsing Values Confirmation',
        buttons: {
            "Normal Parsing": function () {
                $("#hiddenInput").val("Normal Parsing");
            },
            "Buffer Parsing": function () {
                $("#hiddenInput").val("Buffer Parsing");
            }
        }
    })
$("#form").submit();
}

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    <input name="inputName" type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" value="" />
    <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Upload"  onclick="getParsingRoute()" style="width: 100px">Upload</button>
}
```

Comment: hey buddy in the controller, how would i know what the value is ?

Comment: I'm not sure but probably by something that: `var value = Request["inputName"];`

Comment: sorry woocash one question, the dialog box is displaying but it automatically closes and the form submits. it does not pause and let the user select the buttons within dialog box. do i need to add a return false in the dalog box?

Comment: ok so i added an event in form on submit to return false and the dialog box does not dissappear this time. however when they click on a button within the dialog box nothing happens, the form does not post to the controller action method

Comment: Try now with these lines which i added 2min ago.

Comment: with e.stopPropagation(), the dialog box does not even appear. if I remove e.stopPropagation() then it appears but dissappears automatically. I think there might be something else wrong on my page. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try something that:

```
function getParsingRoute(){
  var buttonPressed;
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Parsing Values Confirmation',
        buttons: {
            "Normal Parsing": function () {
                 $.ajax({
                    url: "http://example.com",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: contactForm.serialize() + "&buttonPresed=Normal Parsing" 
                }).done(function (data) {
                    //done
                })
            },
            "Buffer Parsing": function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://example.com",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: contactForm.serialize() + "&buttonPresed=Buffer Parsing" 
                }).done(function (data) {
                    //done
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This code only show you way how you can do it.